# Can anyone help with geometry (area with an unknown length) question? I would really appreciate it.

Tags: geometry

[image]

**Note - the problem I'm struggling with is how to calculate the area of APBQ (the last question)

Figure 1 on the right shows a right-angled
triangle ABC where AB ＝ 1 cm, AC ＝ 2 cm, and
angle BAC ＝ 90°. Triangle PAB is an
isosceles triangle where AP ＝ AB and sides PA
and BC are parallel.
Assume point P is located opposite to point C
with respect to line AB.

Answer the following questions.

〔Question 1 〕 Consider the case in Figure 1 where the magnitude of angle APB is a°.
Find the magnitude of angle ACB in terms of a.

〔Question 2 〕 
Figure 2 on the right shows the case in
Figure 1 where a perpendicular line to
side BC is drawn from vertex A.
Let Q be the intersection of side BC and
the perpendicular line.

Answer （１）and （２）.

（１） Prove triangle ABQ is similar to triangle CAQ.

（２） Calculate the area of quadrilateral APBQ.

Comment: Do you have the working out for all the other parts? This would really help answer the question.

Comment: The first question is irrelevant, and I've already proved the second part (if you see the image you should be able to see the third question). This is what I'm really struggling with.

Comment: ABQ is without a doubt, similar to CAQ

Comment: In part (1) of question 2, you  are asked to show that triangle ABQ is similar to triangle CAQ.  Once you know that, and that side AB is half as long as side BC, you know that the area of CAQ is one fourth the area of ABQ.

Comment: Thank you (this helps!). How about the triangle APB - I don't know what the length of line PB is, is there any way to find this out? (I'm struggling with the third part of q2)

Comment: You don't need $PB$ to find the area. One side and one altitude is enough. You have the side $AP = 1,$ and $AQ$ equals the altitude to that side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question (1):

- If $\angle ~ APB = a^{\circ}$, then $\angle ~ PBA = a^{\circ} $, because $\Delta APB$ is isosceles and $AP = AB$.
- If $\angle ~ APB = a^{\circ} $ and $\angle ~ PBA = a^{\circ} $, then $\angle ~ BAP = 180^{\circ}-2a^{\circ}$.
- If $PA\mathbin{\|} BC$, then $ \angle ~CBA  = 180^{\circ}-2a^{\circ}$ (alternate interior angles).
- If $\angle ~CBA  = 180^{\circ}-2a^{\circ}$ and $\angle~ BAC = 90^{\circ} $, then $\angle ~ ACB = 2a^{\circ}-90^{\circ}$.

Question (2):

[image: The geometrical situation]

- The triangle $\Delta ~ CAQ$ is [similar](https://www.mathopenref.com/similartriangles.html) to the triangle $\Delta ABQ$ because [all three angles](https://www.mathopenref.com/similaraaa.html) in $\Delta ~ CAQ$ are also present in $\Delta ABQ$.
- In $\Delta ABQ$ we have $AQ = \cos(2a^{\circ}-90^{\circ})$ and $BQ = \sin(2a^{\circ}-90^{\circ})$ [by the definitions of the sin and cos functions in a right triangle](https://www.mathsisfun.com/sine-cosine-tangent.html)
- By [the definition of the area of a trapezoid](https://www.mathopenref.com/trapezoidarea.html) we get for the area $A_{APBQ}$ of the trapezoid $APBQ$ the following result: $$  A_{APBQ} = (1/2)\cdot (PA+BQ)\cdot AQ$$
  $$A_{APBQ}=(1/2)\cdot (1+\sin(2a^{\circ}-90^{\circ}))\cdot \cos(2a^{\circ}-90^{\circ})$$

Another way of doing things is $AQ/AB=AC/BC$, because $\Delta BQA \sim \Delta BAC $ are [similar](https://www.mathopenref.com/similartriangles.html). With $BC=\sqrt{AB^2+AC^2}=\sqrt{5}$ we get $AQ = AB \cdot (AC/BC) =  2/\sqrt{5}$. From there we can calculate $BQ = \sqrt{AB^2-AQ^2}=\sqrt{1-(2/\sqrt{5})^2}=1/\sqrt{5}$ and the trapezoid area according to the above formula

$$  A_{APBQ} =  2\Phi/5  $$

where $\Phi=(1+\sqrt{5})/2$ is [the golden ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio).

Comment: Thank you very much - I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Following on from your comment:

$\angle CAB = \tan^{-1} (2)$, and since $PA$ and $BC$ are parallel, $\angle PAB = \tan^{-1} (2)$ as well.

Now if you split $\Delta PAB$ in half where $M$ is the midpoint of $PB$, you will have $\sin PAM = \frac{PM}{PA} = \frac{PM}{1}$. This gives me a value of $PM = \sqrt{\frac{2}{5+\sqrt5}}$ and $PB= \sqrt{2 - \frac{2}{\sqrt5}}$.